# jQuery each and change combined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to combine `each` and `change` with jQuery.

This is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.doetmee').each(function() {
        var thisval = $(this).val()

        if(thisval == 'ja')
        {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv').attr('disabled',false);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv').attr('disabled',true);
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv').val('');
        }

        $('.doetmee').change(function(){
            if(thisval == 'ja')
            {
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv').attr('disabled',false);
            }

            if(thisval == 'nee' || thisval == 'leeg')
            {
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv').attr('disabled',true);
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv').val('');
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

It only changes 1 time and after that it doesn't work.

How can I make sure it works everytime I make a change?

I have tried many things that I could find on stackoverflow or google but without success.

[image]

If the value is `leeg` or `nee` the select on facebook must be disabled.

Comment: you are declaring `var thisval = $(this).val()` outside of the change event. try adding the value inside the change event

Comment: replace  $('.doetmee').change(function(){ ... with $(this).change(function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `each` and `change` register the same function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var updateFields = function() {
        var thisval = $(this).val()

        if(thisval == 'ja')
        {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv').attr('disabled',false);
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv').attr('disabled',true);
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv').val('');
        }
    };

    $('.doetmee').each(updateFields);
    $('.doetmee').change(updateFields);

});
```

In the above example, the function is stored in the variable `updateFields` (so the code is only written once) and is then registered to both `each` and `change`.

Comment: It can also be achieved as `$('.doetmee').change(updateFields).change();`

Comment: Just a comment, improvement.  Could you replace your $(this).parent().parent().find('.facebookadv') to use local var, keeps things a little bit more DRY.

Comment: Yes @Keith I could, however I think it would be best for the OP if I change as little as possible to make the question easier to understand.